# Setting body { font-size: 100% } results in font-size: 12px; and not font-size: 16px; Why?

Tags: css, font-size

I understood that the default font-size was 16px on browsers. Then why is the height of the inline-block(12px) same as the font-size (I've tried in Chrome and FF) ? Please help me understand. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            font: 100% helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.625;
        }
        #tempTest {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 10px;
            height: 12px;
            background-color: orange;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="heading"><span id="tempTest"></span>Remember, when you were young, you shone like a sun. Shine on you crazy diamond</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Remember, when you were young, you shone like a sun. Shine on you crazy diamond". Inspiring. Sorry, I digress.

Comment: in my browser I see 16px

Comment: You haven't accounted for the descenders.  The *R* is 12px tall (Opera 12).  If you measure from the top of the *R* to the bottom of the *y*, it measures 15px, which is close enough to 16px in my book since each browser's text rendering is different.

Comment: Thanks @cimmanon. In retrospect, it seems so obvious. I was trying to get the top of R aligned with another element and ended up with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the inline box using a browser’s Developer Tools (hit F12 to open them), you can see that its height is indeed 12px, as set in your code. This happens because there is nothing in it that would require more height; in general, the exact calculation of heights of inline blocks is browser-dependent.

The font size of the text is still the browser default, typically 16px. The font size does not mean the height of any particular letter. It is just a fundamental property of the font; typographers usually design characters so that they - together with ascenders, descenders, and diacritic marks - fit into the limits set by the font size (or extend over them just a little), and normally most letters have smaller height.

Comment: It does seem a bit strange to me that the bottom of the span element is aligned to the bottom of the letter R, and thus implying that it is not vertically centered with the line-height. I assume that the font-size (font height) is always vertically centered with the line-height.

Comment: @KayaToast, the initial value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`, and it gets applied here. Setting `display: inline-block` does not change this. The font height is usually centered within the line height, but this is not a requirement; it is up to browsers to decide this. But this is distinct from the issue of spacing (within the font height) below the baseline and above the capital height (height of uppercase letters) – these are up to the font designer.

Comment: "This happens because there is nothing in it that would require more height" - wouldn't the height still be 12px even if the contents were larger? My understanding is that the child elements would just overflow outside the boundaries of the inline-block span.